# Vue js component interaction using shared store pattern with vue-loader

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-loader

I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34513716/1291122) SO answer to achieve sibling-sibling data sharing(communcation).

Here is my ComponentA.vue:

```
<template>
    <input id="ca" type="text" v-model="localvarA" placeholder="localvarA">
    <label>{{localvarA}}</label>
    <div>
        thisdiv
        {{sharedvar}}
    </div>
</template>


<script>
    import remoteservice from '../services/applications'
    export default {
        data: function () {
            return {
                localvarA: 'localvalA',
                sharedvar: remoteservice.sharedvar
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

CompoinentB.vue:

```
<template>
    <input type="text" v-model="localvarB" placeholder="localvarB">
    <label>{{localvarB}}</label>
    <div>
        thisdiv2
        <input type="text" v-model="sharedvar" placeholder="sharedvar">
    </div>

</template>


<script>
    import remoteservice from '../services/applications'
    export default {
        data: function () {
            return {
                localvarB: 'localvalB',
                sharedvar: remoteservice.sharedvar
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

And here is my App.vue:

```
<template>
    <component-a></component-a>
    <component-b></component-b>
</template>


<script>
    import ComponentA from './ComponentA.vue';
    import ComponentB from './ComponentB.vue';
    export default {
        components: {ComponentA,ComponentB},
        data: function () {
            return {
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here is my application/index.js (the shared module):

```
export default {
    sharedvar: 'sharedval'
};
```

In above, the shared variable sharedvar when updated in ComponentB does not update its value in div in ComponentA.

I have tried best to replicate in vue-loader the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/WarwickGrigg/xmpLg92c/) in that SO answer, but not sure why this is not working.
Here is the github repo if someone needs to try this out: https://github.com/rahulserver/vueshared-vue-loader

So where am I doing it wrong and how do I make it work?

Comment: I had similar problem to check does it same could you change this in both components `sharedvar: remoteservice.sharedvar` to this `sharedvar: remoteservice`.Then in componentB assign v-model to input like this `sharedvar.sharedvar` - I think this should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring `data` items that are being initialized with the value in `remoteservice.sharedvar`. Because `sharedvar` is a simple value and not an object, they're just separate copies of a value.

In the fiddle example, `hub.state` is an object. If you assign it to a variable, and then reference some member of that variable, you are referencing a member of `hub.state`. In each of their components, they do:

```
hubState: hub.state
```

and then use

```
<input v-model="hubState.message">
```

To parallel that, you should be doing

```
sharedvar: remoteservice
```

and then using

```
 <input type="text" v-model="sharedvar.sharedvar" placeholder="sharedvar.sharedvar">
```

(or change the names to be more sensible). The trick is that you have to work with an object.