# How to set data value of other component in vue js?

Tags: vue.js

I have two component for example `Login.vue` and `Header.vue`. I want to set data value of `header.vue` after some action in `login.vue`. how can i do so?I am using vue cli.

Comment: share your code please, until its too broad

Comment: study this link. it might help you.
https://medium.com/vuejobs/create-a-global-event-bus-in-vue-js-838a5d9ab03a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Login Component is a child of your header, then your Login can emit an event. [See here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html).

If not, then your components can exchange data via a [Global Event Bus](https://web.archive.org/web/20170606062636/http://vuetips.com/global-event-bus)
or a global store [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html).

Also take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34509103/vue-components-communication) on cross component communication.