# Observe to some event from another component in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have two components:

```
<div>
    <advertiser-add-component></advertiser-add-component>
    <advertisers-component></advertisers-component>
</div>
```

These components have the following interface:
[image]

First component is a button. I will see a modal dialog when I click on it. The modal contains an Ajax form:

[image]

Second component is a table. You already saw it on the first picture
So, I would like to rerender the table component after sending the form without page refreshing. Is there some way to "subscribe" to this event (once the modal information is sent) from advertisers-component?  How I can organize it with minimum code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue components communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34509103/vue-components-communication)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes absolutely, for something like this you could spin up a simple event bus, your component would emit an update to the bus, and the other watches for updates to that event type on the bus.

Here's a good example of how to do it:

https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/

Comment: Nice tutorial, but I can't understand where I can put the `EventBus.$on`. Which part of component it is?

Comment: The listener, or $on, should go in your mounted method on your listening component

Comment: mounted() {
            this.getAdvertisersTable();
            EventBus.$on('newAdvertiser', this.getAdvertisersTable())
        }

it's here but it gives me the error 
' Error in event handler for "newAdvertiser": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined"'

Comment: Do this: eventbus.$event bus.('event', this.getAdvertisersTable); dont invoke the method with the parens. Then in your function, add one parameter of value. This is what the event passed forward.

Comment: From the sample linked: EventBus.$on('i-got-clicked', clickHandler);

Answer (score 4):

Im using vue-events package: https://github.com/cklmercer/vue-events

- Install the package globally
- Add events object in your component with the events to listen, and fire the event from the modal, check this example:

  [image: Component with table]
  [image: Modal sending reload event]

Comment: It's look like easy!

Answer (score 1):

I would encourage you to check this: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html

Basically you have a component (or java class) called a store that holds the data of the table. That data is the one displayed by the table. When submitting the modal, you ask the store to fetch the data again (by sending an event) from your backend where I assume the data is stored.

Since the table displays the data of the store already, the table will update itself automatically.

I have done just that in an application of mine here: https://github.com/Draluy/Jobsearch/blob/master/front/src/components/applications/Application.vue

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to wrap your two components in another component that handles the data and the ajax request.

```
<wrap-component> <!-- This component contains the data and handles the ajax request -->
   <advertiser-add-component @click-triggered="ajaxRequest"></advertiser-add-component> <!-- This components emits a click event to the <wrap-component>-component that executes the ajax requests -->
   <advertisers-component :tableData="tableData"></advertisers-component> <!-- This component is passed the data via the tableData prop -->
</wrap-component>

<!-- Inside "wrap-component" -->
data() {
  return {
    tableData: []
  }
},
methods: {
  ajaxRequest() {
   // make the data request here and replace this.tableData with the response data
  }
}

<!-- Inside "advertiser-add-component" -->
methods: {
  // Execute this function, when the button is clicked
  add() {
    this.$emit('click-triggered');
  }
}

<!-- Inside "advertisers-component" -->
props: {
   tableData: {
      type: Array // if the data is an array of course..
   }
}
```

Comment: It's ok but not my way) I would like to have solution without a wrapper. Thank you.