# How to get variable value from a component and assign it to a variable in another component in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

This is my code, i'm not using webpack, just the vuejs cdn.I want to get the value of the districts in the regionComponent to the another variable in the districtComponent and display it.

```js
const regionsComponent = Vue.component('region-component', {
  template: `
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="form-group" >
        <label  class="label-text" for="officeRegion">Region</label> <span class="red">*</span>
        <select class="form-control" id="officeRegion" 
        name="officeRegion"  :value = "value" v-on:input ="updateRegion($event.target.value)">
          <option value='' >Select region</option>
          <option v-for="region in regions" :value="region.regionId">{{region.region}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>`,

  data() {
    return {
      regions:[],
    }
  },
  created(){
    this.getRegions();
  },
  props:['value','districts'],
  methods: {  
    getRegions: function() {
      let apiurl = document.getElementById("apiurl").value;
      let apikey = document.getElementById("apikey").value;
      let headers =  {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'apiKey': apikey
      }
      axios.get(apiurl+'regions/all', {headers: headers})
        .then((res)=>{
        console.log(res.data.data[0].region)
        if(res.data.responseCode === "01"){
          this.regions = res.data.data;
        } else {
          console.log("failed to load regions")
        }
      })
    },
    updateRegion: function(value){
      this.$emit('input', value);
      // console.log(value)
      if(value){
        thisdistricts = this.getRegionDistrict(value)
      }
    },
    getRegionDistrict: function (regionId){
      let apiurl = document.getElementById("apiurl").value;
      let apikey = document.getElementById("apikey").value;
      let headers =  {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'apiKey': apikey
      }
      axios.get(apiurl+'region/districts/all?regionId='+ regionId, {headers: headers})
        .then((res)=>{
        console.log(res.data)
        if(res.data.responseCode==="01"){
          return  this.districts = res.data.data
          // console.log(this.districts)
        }
      })
    }  
  }
})

const districtComponent = Vue.component('district-component', {
  template:`
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label  class="label-text" for="officeDistrict">District</label> <span class="red">*</span>
        <select class="form-control" id="officeRegion" name="officeRegion" v-bind="district" v-on:input= "updateDisct($event.target.value)">
          <option value='' >Select district</option>
          <option v-for="district in districts" :value="district.districtId">{{district.districtName}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>`,

  props:['district'],
  data() {
    return {
      districts:[],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateDisct: function(district){
      this.$emit('input', district);
      console.log(district)  
    }
  }
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#myForm',
  components: {
    vuejsDatepicker,
    regionsComponent,
  },
  data: function (){
    return {}
  }
})
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34509103/vue-components-communication

Comment: thanks for the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) is too complicated for now, you can use the native $root when you need a simple way.

I use Vuex with name spaced modules it is brilliant but it is a large learning curve and the documentation is not really that great on it.

To leverage **$root** you could move `regions` to to the `data` attribute of your `new Vue({})` instance and reference that from anywhere using `this.$root.regions` in script or `$root.regions` in template.

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#myForm',
  components: {
    vuejsDatepicker,
    regionsComponent,
  },
  data: function (){
    return {
        regions: []
    }
  }
})
```

---

```
getRegions: function() {

  ...

  axios.get(apiurl+'regions/all', {headers: headers}).then((res)=>{

    if(res.data.responseCode === "01"){
      this.$root.regions = res.data.data;
    } else {
      console.log("failed to load regions")
    }

  })
},
```

---

```
<select ... >
  <option value='' >Select region</option>
  <option v-for="region in $root.regions" :value="region.regionId">{{region.region}}</option>
</select>
```

This way any component at any nested level can access a global data set without any sharing faff.

> this.$set($root.myGlobal, newValue); can also help out with any
>   reactivity issues in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vuex and have a global store to store your data

Answer (score 0):

With Vuex you can share data/complex state management across components. A Vuex store instance is composed of state, getters, actions, and mutations. In summary, the state "holds" your data, you can retrieve it via your state or the getters. Actions can be async and for example can hold an API call, that later on, you can pass the data from the API call to a mutation that ultimately make the change effectively, mutations cannot be async.

[See: The simplest store](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/#the-simplest-store)

All the operations made with Vuex have a trace of what is happening inside your app. It seems a little daunting at first, but actually, it is really easy to manage your data.